# SQL Server: Changing VARCHAR length using Alter table Alter column command

Tags: sql-server

I have searched through StackOverFlow and I haven't found the answer I am looking for, I am updating column varchar length from 1000 to 2000.

**SQL Server script:**

```
ALTER table [Table_Calculation] 
ALTER column [Column_Text] varchar(2000);
```

**Error:**

> Cannot find the object "Table_Calculation" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Question:
I should have access, I am attempting to run script in a test environment, before I reach out to someone regarding access , I want to make sure my syntax is correct. I have researched online and I feel confident my syntax is correct and if I am missing something, it's a small update, can someone help out?

Thanks!

Comment: I have also  tried Modify command , doesn't work

Comment: are you sure that you are using correct database while executing your alter query?

Comment: What happens if you `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Table_Calculation]`?

Comment: @maulik kansara, Yeah I am sure I am using the right database, I think this might be an access issue.at Filburt, it runs like it should, gives me top 10 results

Answer (score 3):

1. Verify it is a table and not a view
2. Make sure you are in the correct database where the table resides
3. Verify your default schema matches the object schema or better yet, specify the schema on your script.
4. If the above is true, you don't have permissions because the SQL is correct.

Comment: also check schema

Comment: @KeithL Good call. I've never had an overlap in schema object names and hadn't run into that.

Comment: it's not usually an overlap, but the table doesn't exist in the default schema but does in another schema like staging.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with current `alter` script, just make sure you are running your script against right database.

So, i would suggest :

```
USE [DB]
ALTER table [schema].[Table_Calculation] 
ALTER column [Column_Text] varchar(2000);
```

Comment: I attempted this , same error pops, process of elimination points that this has to be an access issue.

Comment: @Onecam. . . Now i would suggest to tell your DBA to do your alter task.